# Has anyone used Protools 11 yet?

Tags: pro-tools-11

Hello,

I am looking at upgrading my PT LE 9 systems to PT 11 and am looking for feedback from those who have used this current system or have heard through the grapevine any positives or negatives regarding the system.

I have done some research on it and so far there has been no negative feedback.

Looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: Keep in mind that you will potentially need to plan for the cost of upgrades for any of your plug-ins (depending on the manufacturer). 11 will use 64-bit AAX plug-ins only, no RTAS whatsoever. I believe even current AAX plug-ins that people are using don't work, because they are 32-bit (though many manufacturers are offering free upgrades from 32-bit to 64-bit AAX).

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used it personally, but I know people who have. Only good things to say on this end as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running 11 on my studio machine and I love it so far. Still waiting for new releases for plug ins like altiverb 7 but everything I can't use in PT I just end up using on the vst rack in SM and print everything down. Kind of a pain but it's a work around.

Answer (score 0):

I am happily using PT 11 on my laptop and everything is working really well. We are still using HD9 at work, and are looking to upgrade when we have the money.

Answer (score 0):

The only negative I can think of is the bounce to disk import feature. Every time I have Pro Tools automatically import after an offline bounce the audio comes in messed up. A simple workaround is to manually import after an offline bounce. Other than that PT 11 has been great to work with. I have been able to use it on a few projects since Waves jumped over to aax.